# Drag Drop Replace javascript jquery

Tags: jquery

I am implementing a drag and drop code, what I have at the moment is 6 dragable and dropable images, what this code does is when an image is dragged over another one they swap also all the images swap places as well (like a sort) what Im tryin to do is only swap positions of the 2 images, leaving the rest alone.

take a look - http://jsfiddle.net/kommandoss/YuRpU/

any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to work for me, When I would drag the image over another image I placed in the upper div it seemed fine, It would replace the image in the upper div and the replaced image is added to the end of the other images. Possibly I am not fully understanding what you are looking for...

I did notice a missing semi colon at the end of this line though:

```
$("#circles").droppable({
    accept: '.circles'
})

$("#circles").droppable({
    accept: '.circles'
});
```

**EDIT:** If you want the elements to remain in a location you need to define parameters to the location they should be contained in. Currently they are basically floating around each other unless you are sorting or strictly identifying parameters for them to reside in.

You could define a div size in your CSS to contain the images into an area, this should help solve you issue.

```
div-name {
   height: 150px; 
   width: 150px;
}
```

This allows the images to stay constrained to an area so they are not simply floating around each other in the page.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I havent added css yet, try draggin the image to the right at you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.sortable()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inventory").sortable();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YuRpU/1/

Comment: sorry my mistake, I havent added css yet, try draggin the image to the right at you will see.