# Dragging and Dropping On A Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

this is what I have at the moment - http://jsfiddle.net/kommandoss/YuRpU/32/

What I want to do is when a letter is dragged over the empty space it stays in that place and the original position of the letter is blank without affecting the possition of the rest of the letters , any suggestions how I should do this, should I make the empty box a div or is there any other ways, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout this **live demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/YuRpU/34/

use table in HTML. and wrap DIV to each image to drop image in it..
i have used HTML5 Drag and Drop property to drag n drop character.

Answer (score 1):

I already answered your question here [Drag Drop Replace javascript jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651279/drag-drop-replace-javascript-jquery/9651327#9651327) Sandeep pretty much did what I did so that's fine. I would say stay away from re-posting similar questions more than once or at least include the link for the old question. May save everyone some time in the future...